# How can I utilize Sharepoint as a DMS with Azure AD Authentication?

Tags: sharepoint-online, react, azure-ad

My company is starting to design and build a customer portal for handling customer documents.
Each of our "customers" is another business and may have multiple users from that business that need access to the documents. Each of the users will be authenticated using our Azure Active Directory. Each of these people may need different permissions depending on their role within their business. We expect roles such as Purchasing/Accounting, Service, and Corporate Agreements.
We currently host these documents on our Sharepoint (internally accessible), and would like to have the documents be accessible only by us and the customer (business) that they pertain to.

1- Is there a way that we can set up the files so they are accessed by specific users?

2- If so, is there a way for us to embed these files/folders in the customer facing app (built with React) so that they can have all of the functionality and version control that the SharePoint UI offers without having to code it all into the app?

3- If embedding is not possible, what would be the best approach? SharePoint REST API? or are there any other possibilities?

4- Can any of the above be achieved by utilizing Metadata fields in Sharepoint?

Comment: When you say “authenticated by our Azure Active Directory” do you mean that you are creating user accounts in your own domain or are you using Azure Active Directory federation?

Comment: We are creating user accounts in our own domain and using an Azure app registration to authenticate the users by having them provide their Azure credentials and utilizing the MSAL library before allowing them to browse the app